# Check for certain words in columns and create another column to assign a value based on which words are present

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The data I have looks like below-

```
Column_A               Column_B           
Hello, how are you      ABC
Good day                DEF
LMN                     Nice day
PQR                     Hello
Hi                      TYU
GHI                     Hi
Good night              STR
RST                     Night
```

What I want to do is if the word Hello, Hi are found in **Column_A or Column_B or both**, I create a new column Type and assign it type X
if the words day, night is found in **Column_A or Column_B or both**, I assign it type Y.

The result should look like below-

```
Column_A               Column_B           Type  
Hello, how are you      ABC               type_X
Good day                DEF               type_Y
LMN                     Nice day          type_Y
PQR                     Hello             type_X
Hi                      TYU               type_X
GHI                     Hi                type_X
Good night              STR               type_Y
RST                     Night             type_Y
```

How to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(CONCAT(Column_A, ' ', Column_B)), r'hello|hi') THEN 'type_X'
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(CONCAT(Column_A, ' ', Column_B)), r'day|night') THEN 'type_Y'
    ELSE 'unknown'    
  END AS Type
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - the output is

```
Row Column_A            Column_B    Type     
1   Hello, how are you  ABC         type_X   
2   Good day            DEF         type_Y   
3   LMN                 Nice day    type_Y   
4   PQR                 Hello       type_X   
5   Hi                  TYU         type_X   
6   GHI                 Hi          type_X   
7   Good night          STR         type_Y   
8   RST                 Night       type_Y
```

A little less verbose version is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Column_A_or_B_or_Both, r'hello|hi') THEN 'type_X'
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Column_A_or_B_or_Both, r'day|night') THEN 'type_Y'
    ELSE 'unknown'    
  END AS Type
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([LOWER(CONCAT(Column_A, ' ', Column_B))]) Column_A_or_B_or_Both
```

obviously with the same output

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there a better way to do the things in with clause? I have almost 3K records all of those records need to be checked for certain words in two columns

Comment: just remove with clause and use your table name instead of `project.dataset.table` - make sense?

Comment: Perfect, the 2nd solution seems to be the one I need. Thanks!